# Word for absolutely bound to occur

Tags: single-word-requests

I keep wanting to use eminent. Maybe the word I'm seeking sounds similar.
Alright thesaurus wizards, you're on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is [imminent](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/imminent):

> **1** About to happen.
>   ‘they were in imminent danger of being swept away’

(From Oxford Dictionaries.)

Comment: Or "inevitable"

Comment: "Imminent" means it's seemingly going to happen soon.  But it's not "certain".

Comment: You can strengthen your answer by copying the linked definition and pasting it into your answer.  Start by clicking on "edit" just to the right of the total number of favorable votes.

Comment: I edited your question to quote the definition and provide the citation. Feel free to change the formatting or any other way I presented it.

Answer (score 2):

[**inevitable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inevitable):

> certain to happen:
>   *Accidents are the inevitable result of carelessness.*